# Deserialize Json Using NewtonJS

Tags: c#, json, wcf, json-deserialization

I have WCF Rest  service  Returns Json , I Get the response Json string but after De-serializing It gives Null object ,Json  contains response object which contains List , before De-serializing string json string shows 3 DTOStundet objects  after De-serializing List shows null

```
string returnValue = Navigator.GET(url, APIHearderCollection);

{
  "GetStudentsListJSONResult":
               {
                 "response":
                       {
                         "DTOStudentList":[
                            {
                              "Address":"Kandy",
                              "Age":20,
                              "CourseName":"Physical Sience",
                              "DateOfBirth":"\/Date(318191400000+0530)\/",
                              "StudentId":1,"StudentName":"Kumar Sangakkara",
                              "TelePhoneNumber":"071975769"
                           },
                           {
                             "Address":"Colombo",
                             "Age":21,"CourseName":"Physical Sience",
                             "DateOfBirth":"\/Date(2658600000+0530)\/",
                             "StudentId":2,"StudentName":"Mahela Jayawardena",
                             "TelePhoneNumber":"071975759"
                           }
                         ],
                       "ResponseStatus":0
                      }
                }
}
```

returnValue  contain this json string to be De-serialize

image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrfY1.png)

this is where  im De-serializing json after this response gets null

```
Response response = (Response)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(returnValue, typeof(Response));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize this way, create separate model class

```
public class NewModel
{
    public Response GetStudentsListJSONResult { get; set; };
}

public class NewModel2
{
    public NewModel Result { get; set; };
}
```

Then

```
NewModel2 response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewModel2>(returnValue);
```

Comment: Still gives null list

Comment: did you check it that your `returnValue` is not null ?

Comment: Yes it is  not null it has there objects in the list

Comment: can you add `Response` model class in question ?

Comment: public class Response
    {
        public int ResponseStatus { get; set; }
        public List<DTOStudent> DTOStudentList { get; set; }
    }

Comment: In your json string, your `response` object appears to be wrapped in another object.

Comment: yes    public class APIResponse
    {
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Then just change @Mostafiz's answer to have that class instead of `Response`.

Comment: yes you just need to change the class for correct output

Comment: APIResponse response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(returnValue);      then Response object getting null

Comment: I have edited your question and add details in answer try this

Comment: GetStudentsListJSONResult is method name

Comment: [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "GetStudentsListJSON/")]
        Root GetStudentsListJSON();    After i remove   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped working well

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need two additional classes like this (the name of the classes are not important and can be whatever you like, the important part are the properties):

```
public class Root
{
    public Result GetStudentsListJSONResult { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

and then use something like this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(returnValue);
var response = root.GetStudentsListJSONResult.response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your De Serialization classes from [JSON Utils](http://jsonutils.com/), you can also add Json properties if you would like for proper C# naming.

Please find your classes generated :

```
public class DTOStudentList
{

    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CourseName")]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DateOfBirth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("StudentId")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("StudentName")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TelePhoneNumber")]
    public string TelePhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{

    [JsonProperty("DTOStudentList")]
    public IList<DTOStudentList> DTOStudentList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ResponseStatus")]
    public int ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class GetStudentsListJSONResult
{

    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{

    [JsonProperty("GetStudentsListJSONResult")]
    public GetStudentsListJSONResult GetStudentsListJSONResult { get; set; }
}
```

Use this to De Serialize as follows :

```
var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(returnValue);
```